# Kubernetes node’s condition based scheduling using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, scheduling, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

Team, needed some assistance..

Pod scheduling based on condition of node that is reported in

`kubectl get node node1 -o yaml`

can we do node.condition based scheduling..the way we have nodeSelector  like below?

```
nodeSelector:
  team.nb/service: services
  nodeType: cpu
```

basically, if a k8s worker node reports below condition in its node.yaml how can I put up helm chart to match that ?

```
  - lastHeartbeatTime: "2020-09-29T00:06:24Z"
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-08-16T12:47:16Z"
    message: kubelet has disk pressure
    reason: KubeletHasNoDiskPressure
    status: "false"
    type: DiskPressure
```

can we build helm_chart based on this value for scheduling pods? such that pods land on it only if the below is True

I was searching google but could not find a clue yet..

```
  nodeConditions:
    reason: KubeletHasNoDiskPressure
    status: True
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use resource constraints to request the disk space you actually need, or better still, avoid needing "lots" of local disk space.

The Kubernetes documentation on [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) notes the options you have available to you: pinning a pod to a specific node, matching by labels, or advising placement based on the presence of other known pods.  It also notes that

> Generally such constraints are unnecessary, as the scheduler will automatically do a reasonable placement (e.g. spread your pods across nodes, not place the pod on a node with insufficient free resources, etc.)....

A cluster can be configured to [make "ephemeral storage" a resource type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage); this includes disk used by the container filesystem.  If you know that you'll need "a lot" of disk space and your cluster is configured for this, you can put an appropriate resource request in your YAML file:

```
containers:
  - name: main
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: 20Gi
```

If you really need that much storage, a [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) is a better match.  If you have multiple replicas you might need a StatefulSet to automatically create a PersistentVolumeClaim per replica.  Note that an `emptyDir` volume counts against the ephemeral-storage limit and doesn't get around this.

If a volume doesn't seem right either, it's worth looking at why you need that much storage.  If you need scratch space for a very large computation, you'll have to put that somewhere.  When I've hit trouble like this, it was a debug-level log file growing out of control and the right answer was to turn down the log level.

Just letting the pod or node crash is a legitimate option!  If a pod crashes, it will generally get restarted (though on the same node; specifying the resource limits correctly is important).  If a node fails then the pods on it will get recreated on different nodes.  If you have a cluster autoscaler and there are nodes that can't be scheduled due to their resource constraints, that will cause there to be more nodes and pods can get rescheduled there.

Comment: i appreciate your explanation and notes: my usecase is: pods if crash lose all the data and work as its experiments and data modelling. so, I have to avoid them crashing but at the same time, smartly not get them scheduled if a is node suddenly went thru a certain condition that is okay for other teams to run their pods on but some teams care their pods don't run when node runs in to that same condition. hence is the challenge. 

will it be possible to label the node with the condition that is set on it such that all teams look at that label and pod are scheduled checking its value. ?

Comment: because i have multiple situations: like one is DNS failures to a certain server, where node dns might be working, but since a particular backend is down, we want to set that as a label on node and pods requiring that look at label and move on. or just directly look at node condition and avoid scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

The Scheduler already does something like this-- if a node has Disk Pressure, the node controller will taint it so that the Scheduler won't place anything else on it.  In other words, if a node has no Disk Pressure, then the Scheduler will place pods there, which seems to be what you want?

> The node controller automatically taints a Node when certain
> conditions are true. The following taints are built in:
>
> node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: Node has disk
> pressure.

You can also adjust your Kubelet configuration such that it evicts pods when there is less than xyz% of the disk left to prevent Disk Pressure.

I know that your question was sort of about Condition Based scheduling, but your specific example of wanting to Schedule pods on Nodes without Disk Pressure is handled out of the box and so there is no reason to do that.

Comment: I agree but the problem is we have some teams who honor some conditions and some teams don't, so we want be in restless server state where logic is left on pods for scheduling themselfs. if they find a condition they like land on node and if some teams dont honor that condition, then they skip that node.